# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `int'. Where is the problem?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to access an element from an array and I am getting this error right here `Console.WriteLine(testChoice[0]);`

Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] m1 = { 100 };
        int a = m1.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

        Console.WriteLine("Type m1 underneath");

        string test;
        test = Console.ReadLine();
        int testChoice;
        testChoice = Convert.ToInt32(test);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testChoice[0]);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: `testChoice` is not an array.

Comment: i just need to access an array element by user input

Comment: To elaborate on @DanielA.White's statement... You have declared `int testChoice;`, which makes it a simple `int`.  Then you tried to index into it as if it was an array (or some other type with an indexed property): `Console.WriteLine(testChoice[0]);`.  I'm guessing you meant `m1`.  By the way, when iterating an array, consider using `arrayVariable.Length` rather than hard-coding the length like you have `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`

Comment: Try: `for (int i = 0; i < m1.Length; i++) { Console.WriteLine(m1[0]); } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable which index you are trying to access, `testChoice`, is not an array. It is an int variable. To print it just get rid of the for loop and the index:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] m1 = { 100 };
    int a = m1.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

    Console.WriteLine("Type m1 underneath");

    string test;
    test = Console.ReadLine();
    int testChoice;
    testChoice = Convert.ToInt32(test);

    Console.WriteLine(testChoice);
     
}
```

To access an array element by user input:

```
//class variable
private static int _testChoice;

static void Main()
{
   
    int[] testChoices = { 100, 200, 300 };
    //int a = m1.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

    //Console.WriteLine("Type m1 underneath");

    string indexInput;
    Console.WriteLine("Please specify the index:");
    indexInput = Console.ReadLine();
    int index;
    index = Convert.ToInt32(indexInput );

    _testChoice = testChoices[index];
    Console.WriteLine(_testChoice);
}
```

Comment: i need to access an array element by user input and use it outside the scope

Comment: Please see if my updated answer helps. _testChoice's scope is the class so you can use it outside `Main()`.

Comment: Thanks, give me few minutes :)

Comment: somehow the last line gives an error Unexpected symbol `Console'. I used your code 1:1 . Trying to solve this

Comment: A `;` was missing on the line before that

Comment: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Program._testChoice'

Comment: Make `_testChoice` static

Comment: It works! I will send you flowers!

Comment: Alright then accept my answer, cheers